# Keep cell value same if condition is not met

Tags: google-sheets

**Set-up**

I have 2 Google sheets.

Sheet 1 imports a cell value from Sheet 2 using the `IMPORTRANGE` function.

The cell value in Sheet 2 is updated automatically each day, 365 days a year.

Sheet 1 contains data on 1 month only.

---

**Issue**

I need to create an `IF` formula using the `IMPORTRANGE` in Sheet 1 such that the cell value in Sheet 1 keeps the data from the last day of the month if the current date is a new month.

E.g. on February 1, the cell in Sheet 1 needs to display the data from January 31 and not from February 1, even though `IMPORTRANGE` imports the cell value from Sheet 2 which will contain data on February 1.

---

**Pseudo formula**

So, if Sheet 1 is about January, the formula in the cell in Sheet 1 should be something along the lines of,

`IF(today(month())=1;IMPORTRANGE(Sheet2_url,cell_range);DONTCHANGEVALUE)`

How do I go about?

Comment: I need: If the condition is NOT met -> do NOT change cell value. 

Not sure how `=eomonth` would help with that?

Comment: The IMPORTRANGE part isn't really necessary. I suggest you to add some sample date directly into the question as well a link to a demo spreadsheet shared with anyone with the link to view only.